# WiFi HT40 Android device sync missing

Tags: wi-fi, gmail, exchange

I am using Samsung Galaxy S III and Galaxy Note II, and both I have noticed in specifications are "WiFi HT40: supported". My problem is, that when I have mobile data active and connect to Wi-Fi, and try to sync with Gmail or Exchange it does not work. Older devices (Galaxy S II, Galaxy S, Galaxy Ace) were working without problems.

Do you think this has something to do with WiFi HT40? Is there any way how to disable it? When I am on Wi-Fi with no mobile data, everything works fine, when I allow mobile data, sync does not work. I have contacted operator, cellphone maker, but still no solution ...